# 16bit wine application has red background

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I'm trying to run an old Win 3.1 program on Wine, latest on ubuntu 19.10 (also testing on 18.04).

It works OK but the background is all red, so makes all images look funny. I think it's supposed to be white?

Any ideas? using WINEARCH=win32 and trying all windows versions from 3.1 to windows 10, all behave the same. I unchecked window manager window decoration and control. It's supposed to look like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Rtjujfhfcc

But looks like:
[image]

Comment: Also askable as _How do I get my 256-colour application running under WINE to display properly on a direct colour X display?_.  (-:

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I found this a winehq link with some info but it ended up looking worse (https://wiki.winehq.org/256_Color_Mode) Do you have any other suggestions?